# CruiseControl.NET email to only modifying users

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to send mail on successful builds to only modifying users dynamically via CruiseControl.NET?

In CCNET build logs there's a section about modifying users but only user code value exists there.

Is it possible to integrate this information with exchange server and get the user email then send only all modifying users a mail like `Your modifications successfully transferred vs vs`?

Comment: Would that not be answered (or asked) on the developers site?

Answer (score 3):

From my knowledge, the email blocks in CC.NET are static. I do not think you could dynamically create email recipients, unless you used a mechanism outside of CC.NET, such as Powershell.

You always could run a script that could generate your email list (based on your source control information), and set that email recipient string list to a system level variable in your environment variables, then reference that environment variable in your email blocks of CC.NET.